# Copy and paste the curve of a path? illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

Is there a way to copy and paste the curve of this path to the other side? I know you can mirror the path but that I assume would mean I have to cut the path in half then mirror flip and then join the paths back together.

[image]

Comment: Cut, flip a copy, and join is how most handle it. In fact, it would take less time than posting this question took. You can't make one path mimic another.

Comment: @Scott though you could use the transform effect to mirror one half then it would automatically mirror the other thalf. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x17DB.jpg

Comment: @joojaa True, but that's not really mimicking one path to another *existing* path `:)`

Answer (score 1):

How to make it symmetric afterwards; get two versions without cutting it.

[image]

1.The not so perfectly symmetric path

2.A flipped copy is made by applying Object > Transform > Reflect > Vertical > Copy

3a. The result when the versions are united

3b. It's the 3a, but the bottom nodes (=anchor points) are aligned and the top nodes are aligned.

4a. The result when the versions are intersected

4b. It's the 4a, but the bottom nodes are aligned and the top nodes are aligned.

To align a bunch of nodes select them at first with the direct selection tool.

Instead of aligning you can for better control remove the unwanted nodes with the "Delete Anchor Point"-tool It's under the pen in the toolbox.